# $_SESSION not working in symfony2.1

Tags: php, session, symfony

I have upgraded the symfony2.0 project to symfony2.1.3. All the module working same as old version, but the `$_SESSION` is not working in new version.

How can I get all data of the session in my Symfony app? I would like the session to be shared between the 2 applications.

Answer (score 2):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

$data = $session->all();
```

The `$data` variable will now contain the session data.

Comment: Agreed.  One of the nice things about using a framework like Symfony is that it abstracts things like the $_SESSION and $_REQUEST variables.  It's nice to avoid direct access to things like this in your application because developers invariably cannot resist the urge to write to these inappropriately.